# How to auto-generate an interface implementation in vscode

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-code, interface-implementation

auto-generate an interface implementation in Visual Studio Code

I know this is quite lazy but, is there any way on Visual Studio Code to auto-generate an interface implementation? (I don't mean at runtime but at design time, like a code snippet). Perhaps with a third party utility?

Comment: possibly related historical bug: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4890. Do you not get a right-click menu action to implement an interface? Also related feature-request: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/2392